# Yodlee AddSiteAccount and GetItemSummaries don't return expected results

Tags: php, api, yodlee

So, we've been using the Yodlee RESTful API with a PHP implementation, but we're getting an inconsistent issue when adding site accounts, which results in further issues with item summaries returning "**Api execution successful. No data found for the API.**"

Sometimes, only sometimes, when getting a response from the "*SiteAccountManagement/addSiteAccount1*" Yodlee API call, the first time it's called, the return data looks like so:

```
...
siteRefreshInfo => object(stdClass) {
    siteRefreshStatus => object(stdClass) {
            siteRefreshStatusId => (int) 1
            siteRefreshStatus => 'REFRESH_TRIGGERED'
    }
    siteRefreshMode => object(stdClass) {
            refreshModeId => (int) 2
            refreshMode => 'NORMAL'
    }
    updateInitTime => (int) 1405406124
    nextUpdate => (int) 1405407024
    code => (int) 801
    suggestedFlow => object(stdClass) {
            suggestedFlowId => (int) 2
            suggestedFlow => 'REFRESH'
    }
    noOfRetry => (int) 0
}
...
```

Which will later result in the "*DataService/getItemSummariesForSite*" API call returning **"Api execution successful. No data found for the API."**.

However, upon a making a new call to these API functions (by just refreshing the page), the return data for "*SiteAccountManagement/addSiteAccount1*" will look like this:

```
...
siteRefreshInfo => object(stdClass) {
        siteRefreshStatus => object(stdClass) {
            siteRefreshStatusId => (int) 10
            siteRefreshStatus => 'SITE_CANNOT_BE_REFRESHED'
        }
        siteRefreshMode => object(stdClass) {
            refreshModeId => (int) 2
            refreshMode => 'NORMAL'
        }
        updateInitTime => (int) 0
        nextUpdate => (int) 1405575826
        code => (int) 0
        suggestedFlow => object(stdClass) {
            suggestedFlowId => (int) 1
            suggestedFlow => 'NOT_REFRESHABLE'
        }
        itemRefreshInfo => array(
            (int) 0 => object(stdClass) {
                memItemId => (int) 11529165
                itemSuggestedFlow => object(stdClass) {
                    suggestedFlowId => (int) 1
                    suggestedFlow => 'NOT_REFRESHABLE'
                }
                itemSuggestedFlowReason => object(stdClass) {
                    suggestedFlowReasonId => (int) 5
                    suggestedFlowReason => 'RECENTLY_REFRESHED'
                }
                errorCode => (int) 0
                retryCount => (int) 0
            }
        )
        noOfRetry => (int) 0
    }
...
```

What could be causing the addition of sites to be returning a code 801, and what does said code represent?

We've followed the recommended Yodlee API procedures in the quickstart guide, and most of the time, things are working well.

Comment: Offtopic: I didn't know something was named so close to my name...

Answer (score 0):

Actually the status code 801 represents 
"Request In Progress: Please wait while we update your account."

So when you refresh your page for the next time the refresh of the add site account might get completed so that you will get the list of added account details.

Refer the link below for the representation of different status codes.
[Error Codes](http://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes)